# ftplib prints call stack when connection fails

Tags: python, traceback, ftplib

I'm using `ftplib` in python to connect to a FTP server. The problem is that whenever the connection fails, `ftplib` prints traceback even though I'm using exception handling to print a message of my choice in case of connection failure.

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp_cui = FTP(ip, username, password, timeout=5.0)

try:
    ftp_cui.connect(port=21)

except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    print("error")
```

How do I suppress this behavior of `ftplib`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from ftplib import FTP

try:
    ftp_cui = FTP(ip, username, password, timeout=5.0)
    ftp_cui.connect(port=21)
except:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Note that this catches all exceptions, not only the ones in ftplib.all_errors

Answer (score 0):

I moved the line with the initialization also into the try block, then it shows your desired message "error" only:

```
from ftplib import FTP, all_errors

try:
    ftp_cui = FTP(ip, username, password, timeout=5.0)
    ftp_cui.connect(port=21)

except all_errors as e:
    print("error")
```